# Touch feedback on Elements broken

Tags: android

in my current app i have a strange effect. Throughout the whole app the touch feedback is some kind of broken. It seems that at a touch an image of a shadow is rendered onto the elements. This only happends on API 20 and lower.

Any idea what can cause this effect and how to fix this?

[image]

**Edit**

I think i finally solved it. I looks like it somehow depends on Java 8. Since i switched back to Java 7 the problems are gone.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Are these custom ImageViews you have defined?

Comment: That happens on default Elements. The effect also occurs when i touch radiobuttons and checkboxes.

Comment: Sure, there is a shadow touch event on non-material elements. It was replaced with the ripple effect at Lollipop... Is that what you mean? Is something wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, it looks as if this touch shadow is rendering wrong in my case. It gets rendered as seen in the picture...

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to show in that image. Is that the pressed state or normal state?

Comment: thats the pressed state. All other states are fine.. the clipping is a bit small sorry..

Comment: Do you have a selector xml in those resources that is drawing some other 9-patch file? I still don't know if it's a problem with native Android components or code you've written

Comment: hmm, i don't use any 9-patch files in my app..

Comment: I think i found it.. it was caused by an external lib which I had included.. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: Could you answer below if you have found a solution? It may help others find the problem

Comment: Hey I have the same problem. What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still there. Some times the buttons are drawing correctly the other elements like radio and checkboxes are always broken.

Comment: with me it's always with menu items, the problem cannot be in external libraries because even if I create new project and set menu items there, the same thing happens

Comment: I think the problem occured after I updated jdk from 1.7 to 1.8