# weird behavior of menu items in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem

I have a really weird problem. sdk and android have filled up my C disk space, so I uninstalled and deleted everything and installed android studio from scratch. and I continued to work on my projects. however, all my projects that I have built since then, show strange behaviour. when I press menu items both on the toolbar or in navigation drawer, while they are pressed, they show black borders around them.

See the pictures[image] below:
[image: http://postimg.org/image/gex9x5v6j/]

Comment: Two questions:

1) Have you stored any project files inside the now-deleted android studio files? 2) Where is the code?

Comment: 1) project files are on D disk 2) I did not change anything in code... and the new projects also, that I start in my new android studio have the same problem

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750190/touch-feedback-on-elements-broken?noredirect=1#comment62971817_37750190

Comment: It was because of jdk 1.8 which I updated recently